# How to "punctualize" this prospective title for a poem I'm writing:

Tags: punctuation

The title: Sick

But I want the 's' to represent:

- The capitalization of the title
- It actually be written in the lower case, as to represent the Latin word "sic"; the translation meaning to be "thus", despite the word changing depending on tense.
- The 'k' being in parentheses, given the title is meant to indicate to the reader the Latin *thus*.

Therefore, I was thinking the title would be written out thus: ([s]ic(k))
, with a triple underline under the 's', for capitalization.

Right? Technically correct? Readability is a low concern.

Comment: I don't think anyone seeing that title will understand that you mean both *sic* and *Sick*.

Comment: Just curious - why is readability a low concern? Usually that's a pretty big deal with poetry.

Answer (score 2):

## Methinks you're overthinking this.

My suggestion is to simply title it: sic

Here's why:

1. The S need not be capitalized
2. The word is still recognizable as [sic]. It retains its meaning regardless of capitalization.
3. I understand that it doesn't contain all the letters in the word 'sick.' However, 'sic' and 'sick' are homophonic. Assuming the dual purpose of your title is reflected in the poem, readers should be able to pick up on this.
4. Triple underlining, parenthesizing, bracketing, and splicing the same one word is too complicated for the purpose that you are trying to achieve. Like I said earlier, give your readers some credit; let *them* be the ones to discover your meaning.

If you really want the title to be more thought-provoking, you could try 'Sic', 'S ic,' 'Sic k,' 'S ic k' or something similar. **There is no need to overcomplicate a title with esoteric punctuation--let the reader derive meaning from the poem itself.**

Answer (score 0):

In poetry, punctuation is optional.

Take E.E. Cummings

[image: first few lines of since feeling is first]

No periods. No capitalization. He's using language and syntax to craft his expression.

If you want to decorate your title in any given way to emphasize some idea or influence the vibe of your piece, go ahead, [k]nock yourself out.

Answer (score 0):

To get the valency of both "sick" and "sic" I would simply write it as follows: [sic]k.  Parenthetical "sic" is what most people are familiar with and will communicate the double entendre.  All the other parenthetical marks in your original suggestion are simply redundant and confusing.  Regarding capitalization, you don't need it.  I read professionally published poetry all the time with lower case titles, here is one example from a recent collection:

https://poems.com/poem/i-am-like-a-radio-channel-of-my-own/